# How to secure Axis2 web services?

Tags: java, web-services, apache, apache-axis

is that secure everyone can access wsdl  through the apache home page of Axis2 web services?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I wanted to ask this question."_is that secure everyone can access wsdl through the apache home page of Axis2 web services?_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, for instance, if you were exposing the Axis2 web service over Tomcat, you could limit the servlet endpoint through either a username and password, or by IP range access.  Consider [reading this documentation on Tomcat if you want to limit access](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter).

To secure this endpoint further you could supply your HTTP server with a certificate so the data is transferred over HTTPS.